# Web services configuration exception LightSwitch

Tags: web-services, deployment, visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm having problems when deploying an application with a Web Service consume from the Client.. I followed this article

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/LightSwitch-Consuming-Web-c54979e0

I tryed to add the `ServiceReferences.ClientConfig` to the `Web.config` in the corresponding serviceModel section but some parts of my app stop working, but no Exception...

When the Application tries to consume the WS it gives me this message

```
Error al ejecutar la pantalla.
Detalles del error: [SFxConfigLoaderMultipleEndpointMatchesWildcard1]
Argumentos: ServiceAuxiliar.IAuxiliar
Las cadenas de recursos de depuración no están disponibles. La clave y los argumentos suelen proporcionar suficiente información para diagnosticar el problema. Vea http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=5.0.10411.00&File=System.ServiceModel.dll&Key=SFxConfigLoaderMultipleEndpointMatchesWildcard1
```